# Where do I put GC.KeepAlive?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, unmanaged

I need to register a callback in unmanaged code, but it looks like GC keeps collecting my reference. So I added `GC.KeepAlive(callback_pin);` but it has no effect. I'm not sure where should I put `GC.KeepAlive`.

This is the code where I register my own callback to the unmanaged event, it is called from a thread. (Some_Callback and Some_Method are external objects)

```
var callback_pin = new Some_Callback(MyManagedCallback);
GC.KeepAlive(callback_pin);
Some_Method(callback_pin);
return true;
```

And below is how I imported the unmanaged code. The documentation which came with it suggests that I use the above-mentioned code in order to keep the callback alive, but since the callback is never fired in my case I don't think it's the right way to do it. Any enlightenments?

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public delegate void Some_Callback(Int32 line, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string msg);

[DllImport("SOME_DLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern Int32 Some_Method(MulticastDelegate funcPtr, Int32 mask);
```

Comment: Have you tried putting it at the end of the routine?

Comment: @JoeSewell No not yet, but I'll try it right now

Comment: @JoeSewell I tried it and it didn't make a difference

Comment: You mention that the callback is "disposed" - you mean in the sense that something calls `Dispose` on it? That's not the same thing as garbage collection. If the callback object is disposed before the unmanaged code uses it, the object will still exist in memory, but the unmanaged code may not be able to use the object, depending on the semantics the object has for being disposed.

Comment: @JoeSewell sorry it was being ambiguous, I meant to say the callback is not getting called. it is not disposed.

Comment: Have you tried to make `callback_pin` a field instead of a local variable?

Comment: @JoeSewell yes, no difference

Comment: A keepalive keeps the reference alive *until* the keepalive, so it has to go *last*, and the root is allowed to disappear immediately after the last keepalive. But that said, you've presented no evidence whatsoever that your problem is that the GC is collecting your delegate. Your symptom is that the delegate is not being called. If it was being collected before it was called by unmanaged code then probably you'd crash the runtime. Figure out who is supposed to be calling the delegate and why it is not.

Comment: @EricLippert yes you're probably right, I get no error. And this was reassuring: `A keepalive keeps the reference alive until the keepalive, so it has to go last`

Answer (score 2):

Delegates are automatically "kept alive" (the technical term is "rooted") for the duration of native functions in which they participate as parameters.

You only need special code to keep them alive if the native function you're calling is only storing the pointer, then at some later point another function (or thread) uses the stored pointer. The framework could conceivably garbage collect your delegate by then.

Besides, your issue is different, if the delegate was garbage collected you'd be getting an access violation when calling it. If nothing is happening, your native function simply isn't calling it -- debug it!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, yes it should be something else since I don't get any errors. I would debug it if I had the source code, but I'm trying to guess what's happening behind the scenes and to figure out what does the vendor meant by suggesting the usage of keepAlive.

Comment: You're kind of SOL then, it's an API related issue for sure, and since we don't know your API we probably can't help you there.

Comment: I don't expect them to know the answer so I had to make sure my understanding of the subject is good enough first. Thanks for the help :-)