# Local keyboard hook terminates the target process

Tags: c#, c++, hook

I'm trying to install a **LOCAL** keyboard hook into a process using a C++ DLL from managed C# code, as follows:

```
public class KeyboardHook
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    protected static extern IntPtr Install(int idHook, IntPtr windowHandle, HookCallback callback);

    private IntPtr instance;
    private HookCallback handler;

    public KeyboardHook()
    {
        instance = IntPtr.Zero;
        handler = Callback;
    }

    public void Install(Process process)
    {
        instance = Install(WH_KEYBOARD, process.MainWindowHandle, handler);
    }

    public void Uninstall()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(instance);
    }

    private IntPtr Callback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        // TODO Use hook data here

        return CallNextHookEx(instance, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

The C++ DLL code should be just enough to dispatch the hook data to the C#'s `Callback` function, like this:

```
// dll.h
#pragma data_seg(".foo")
HOOKPROC _hookCallback = NULL;
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.foo,RWS")
#pragma data_seg()

static HINSTANCE _moduleHandle = NULL;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
HHOOK Install(int idHook, HWND window, HOOKPROC hookCallback);

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int code, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);

// dll.cpp
HHOOK Install(int idHook, HWND window, HOOKPROC hookCallback)
{
    auto processId = 0ul;
    auto threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, &processId);

    _hookCallback = hookCallback;
    _hookCallback(-1, NULL, NULL); // Test callback (works)

    return SetWindowsHookExA(idHook, HookProc, _moduleHandle, threadId);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // The following line terminates the target process
    return _hookCallback(code, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            _moduleHandle = hModule;
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

The local hook is successfuly installed as the DLL KeyboardProc function is triggered, however, calling the C# delegate from the C++ DLL terminates the application. Why?

**NOTES:**

1. Both the DLL and the application are 32 bits
2. `_hookCallback_` is not null when `HookProc` is triggered (although I'm not sure whether it points to a valid memory address)
3. `KeyboardProc::handler` shouldn't be garbage collected, as the KeyboardProc instance lives for as long as the C# application does
4. Using `_hookCallback` function pointer within the DLL's `Install` function works flawlessly, but terminates the process when used inside the `HookProc` function.
5. There's no exception or whatsoever, the process just terminates abruptly

**WHAT ALSO HAVE BEEN TRIED:**

Making `HookCallback` a `UnmanagedFunctionPointer`, as well as using `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` and telling the garbage collector not to collect the `handler` property by using `GCHandle.Alloc()` and `GC.KeepAlive()`:

```
public class KeyboardHook
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("DLL32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    protected static extern IntPtr Install(int idHook, IntPtr windowHandle, IntPtr delegatePointer);

    // ...
    
    protected readonly GCHandle garbageCollectorHandle;
    
    public KeyboardHook()
    {
        instance = IntPtr.Zero;
        handler = new HookCallback(Callback);
        garbageCollectorHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(handler); // Or GC.KeepAlive(handler)
    }
    
    ~KeyboardHook()
    {
        garbageCollectorHandle.Free();
    }
    
    public void Install(Process process)
    {
        IntPtr delegatePointer = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(handler);
        
        instance = Install(WH_KEYBOARD, process.MainWindowHandle, delegatePointer);
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Using `handler` directly into `SetWindowsHookExA` (C++):

```
HHOOK Install(int idHook, HWND window, HOOKPROC hookCallback)
{
    auto processId = 0ul;
    auto threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, &processId);

    _hookCallback = hookCallback;

    return SetWindowsHookExA(idHook, hookCallback, _moduleHandle, threadId);
}
```

Comment: Add `GC.KeepAlive(handler);` in another function, perhaps in `Uninstall`

Comment: @Charlieface could you explain? The `HookProc` terminates the process right away, not only after the hook has been uninstalled.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952678/where-do-i-put-gc-keepalive Although knowing the exact exception would help

Comment: That's the problem. I have no idea what kind of exception occurs. The process terminates abruptly.

Comment: If you need the function pointer to stay alive *outside* the life of `Install` then you need to `KeepAlive` on the delegate outside of `Install`. If you look at Windows Event Viewer -> Application Events you should find the exception there. What I don't get is why this needs another C++ dll at all, you can do the whole thing from C#.

Comment: @Charlieface no, you can't. Local hooks must reside within a C++ DLL. The problem going on here isn't related to garbage collection, it's related to inter-process communication as processes use different virtual memory regions. Read my discussion below with Remy.

Comment: I'm completely confused. If these are actually two separate processes (which you hadn't mentioned before) then why would you think that a function pointer in one process would work in another? But P/Invoke with `DllImport` only works in the same process, so I don't get what it is you are doing. Please elaborate on the exact setup of the C++ and C# dlls, and how many processes are involved

Comment: I know what a keyboard hook is. You are installing a local hook. I still don't get your use case. Is this a hook on a thread in a different process or the same process? And why can you not do this all in C#? Even if it was a global hook you could make a separate C# dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process terminates due to accessing an invalid memory address.

Every Windows process have different [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) regions. In other words, the `0x1234` memory address within the process `A` does not point to the same value/function as `0x1234` memory address within the process `B`, since `0x1234` is a virtual memory address bound to it's corresponding process.

In order to achieve that communication between a C++ DLL and a C# application (any different process overall), an [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (IPC) is required.

For those interested on this specific case, I ended up creating an [invisible dummy window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589643/dispatching-managed-win32-wndproc-on-a-sepparate-thread) to serve as a central point for receiving messages through `SendMessage` calls from the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

The C# code is calling the DLL's `Install()` function with the 2nd and 3rd parameters flipped.

Change this line:

```cs
instance = Install(WH_KEYBOARD, handler, process.MainWindowHandle);
```

To this:

```cs
instance = Install(WH_KEYBOARD, process.MainWindowHandle, handler);
```

**UPDATE**: Also, you did not show the C# code's declaration of the DLL'S `Install()` function.  But in the C++ code, the `Install()` function is not specifying a calling convention, so it will (likely, depending on compiler config) default to `__cdecl`  (`HookProc()` is using the `__stdcall` calling convention).  So make sure the C# code is specifying the correct calling convention when importing the `Install()` function.  C# `delegate`s use `__stdcall` by default.

Comment: That was actually a typo, my bad. I edited the post to also include the DLL function import. The problem resides in HookProc, when calling a C# delegate from C++.

Comment: @Henri there is no difference whatsoever between the call to `_hookCallback()` in `Install()` vs in `HookProc()`, so something else is going on.

Comment: Yea, but what could be going on? @Charlieface talked about garbage collection, but I don't think that's the problem either, as the `KeyboardHook` instance lives for as long as the C# application does.

Comment: @Henri do you have the same problem if you use [`Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate?view=net-5.0) when passing the `handler` to `Install()`? See [Delegates As Callbacks Part 2](https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/delegates-as-callbacks-part-2/) for details. It also covers the garbage collection issue.

Comment: By installing the hook into a dummy WinForms C# application, I could find in the Windows Event Viewer a .NET Runtime error at `UnsafeNativeMethods.PeekMessage(MSG ByRef, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32, Int32, Int32)` within that dummy application, if that helps.

Comment: @Henri the keyboard hook is called in the context of message retrieval in the thread that is hooked. You already knew the callback handler was crashing inside that keyboard hook. Have you tried using a try/catch inside the `HookProc()`? Also, are you SURE the `handler`/`KeyboardHook` is not being garbage-collected? Have you tried `Uninstall()`'ing the hook when `KeyboardHook` is no longer alive? Please provide a [mcve] on the C# side showing how `KeyboardHook` is being used.

Comment: I was adding a try/catch block by the time you replied. The `catch` isn't triggered within `HookProc`. I am not sure whether the `handler` property is not being garbage collected, but I'm telling the garbage collector not to collect it, using both `GCHandle.Alloc()` and `GC.KeepAlive()`. I haven't bothered with `Uninstall` yet. The `KeyboardHook` is being used in a WinForms application, on which source code can be found here https://github.com/YvesHenri/local-hooks (but could be used in a console application by simply instantiating a `KeyboardHook` and calling `Install`.

Comment: Could this problem be related to processes virtual memory allocation? As when we pass the `Hook::handler` function pointer to the C++ DLL, we are passing the C#'s application memory address, eg 0x00001234. The C++ `HookProc` function is called within the target process virtual memory region, that means the address `0x00001234` within that process is pointing to anywhere else. Could this be it? I'm gonna try `WriteProcessMemory()` as I'm completely out of ideas if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Henri sounds reasonable, if you are hooking across process boundaries (<slaps head> why didn't I think of that? Must be too late at night). A `WH_KEYBOARD` hook is called in the thread that is hooked. You would have to use inter-process communication to send the key info back to your main process, such as with `(Post|Send)Message()`, etc. That is not the necessary with a `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook, which is called in the thread that installs it, but as such it can't hook a specific thread by ID, only globally.

Comment: Yea, that might be it. However, `(Post|Send)Message` is out of mind, as it would require custom message registration and window handles. I also need synchronous communication as I might want to block certain hooks (return 1). By the way, I'm a big fan of yours and Hans Passant. I started coding more than a decade ago with C++ Borland and found many of your posts over the internet. Just thought you'd like to read this. :)

Comment: @Henri there are many forms of IPC, window messages were just an example (and FYI, `SendMessage()` is synchronous). Use whatever suits your needs.