# Suitable IPC between a C++ DLL (local hooks) and C# application

Tags: c++, com, hook, ipc, rpc

Whats the best inter-process communication for a C++ DLL that's injected into a third-party process and a C# application? Here's the current situation:

```
// This gets executed within the target process memory region
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code > 0)
    {
        auto csharpApplicationFunctionPointerAddress = 0xdeadbeef;
        auto csharpApplicationFunctionResult = call csharp function with N parameters here

        // Do something with the result
        if (csharpApplicationFunctionResult == "foo")
        {
            
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hookInstance, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66486015/local-keyboard-hook-terminates-the-target-process) and figured out I'd need a RPC, however I can't seem to find the best suitable RPC for this problem, as that communication requires passing N parameters and getting the result back as fast as possible.

**NOTES:**

1. Sockets are out of mind as I dont want to deal with timeouts
2. Would named pipes work here or it's only advisable for string messages?(serialization/deserialization is out of mind)
3. I do not want to use message polling with a remote thread, as this uses too much CPU

Are even there any options left? Feel free to correct me the notes above.

Comment: On Windows IPC is basically represented by: sockets, named pipes, shared memory and message queues. So, looks like your the only option is shared memory.

Comment: `WM_COPYDATA` is very simple if you have a message queue at the receiving end https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-copydata  Next easiest is UDP (no timeouts)

Comment: There are other forms of IPC available - mailslots, RPC, ActiveX/COM, DDE, etc.  But even if you were to use sockets or pipes, you don't have to poll for inbound messages, you can let the OS notify you of new messages via Overlapped I/O or I/O Completion Ports. Butt honestly, I would just use window messages, they are very simple and do not use up a lot of overhead, despite the OP's claim to the contrary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up creating an [invisible dummy window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589643/dispatching-managed-win32-wndproc-on-a-sepparate-thread) to serve as a central point for receiving messages through `SendMessage` calls from the DLL.